# How can I prevent CMake from printing information about a selected preset's variables and environment during config?

Tags: cmake

When using CMakePresets.json, CMake outputs information related to the presets during configuration. Example:

```
Preset CMake variables:

  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:FILEPATH="K:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
```

Is there a way to tell CMake to omit outputting that information? I just don't want that noise outputted, unless I specifically ask for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be impossible to do, there is no mention of a flag to silent/quiet those cached vars when using presets in cmake

Sources:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from inspecting the source code with respect to the `cmake::ProcessPresetVariables` and `cmake::ProcessPresetEnvironment` functions (the functions themselves, and their call sites, which you can find in [Source/cmake.cxx](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmake.cxx)), at the time of this writing (CMake ~3.27 being the latest version), there is no way for the user to tweak whether this information gets printed for commandline invocations besides building a custom CMake build where that function is not called. `#ifndef CMAKE_BOOTSTRAP` in the call-site is a red-herring- if I understand correctly, it's for building CMake itself.

If you want such a feature to be added, raise it as a feature request either on https://discourse.cmake.org/ or https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues.

Aside: The asker of this question calls this printed information "noise". I can sympathize, but I wouldn't be so quick to call it noise. It can be non-trivial to manually figure out what variables something will get with multiple and/or nested preset configuration inheritance by just visual inspection of a CMakePresets.json file. Add to that that preset files can include other preset files, so it's not necessarily just looking at one file. How much it helps depends on context, workflow, and the user's experience with CMake.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.